# jh_opengraph_ttnews not generate og meta tag when start date item was in future for news

Tags: facebook, typo3, meta-tags, tt-news

i am using `jh_opengraph_ttnews` extension adds some Open Graph protocol meta-tags to the html-header when showing a tt_news item in single view.
it is working fine when startdate in not in future.
when i give startdate in future it is not generate `og:` meta-tags
i.e. today is 7th july 2017 if i give startdate is 8th july 2017 or any date after 7th july it will not working.

need a quick help.
any help appriciated.

Comment: If your `startdate` of news will be in future then, that news will not be displayed.

Comment: ok.
Thanks for your reply